# hibernate map java Long to MySQL BIGINT error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i have a table with id field type BIGINT in MySQL

in hibernate object, i use java Long type for this field

but when run program, it throw exception:
`Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer`

how to map MySQL BINGINT datatype in hibernate ?

Comment: Using a Long for a BIGINT is correct. Please show your mapping, the code you're running and the full stacktrace.

Comment: ok, i defi wrong param for my method cellDao.get(Integer id).
i fix it & now it run well. thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but when run program, it throw exception: Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer

Using a `Long` for a BIGINT is correct and the above error suggests that you are somehow passing an `Integer` where a `Long` is expected somewhere in your code. Double check your code.

Answer (score 6):

Does it help if you add a  **columnDefinition** like  *columnDefinition = “bigint(20)″* to your mapping parameters?

Comment: i use hibernate xml config file, & dont know how to config columnDefinition param :|

Comment: I'm sorry but how could this possibly help?

Comment: Sometimes hibernate can not figure out how to correctly map the sql-type, but you are right, in that case the error message looks slightly different.
  
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in TEST.EXAMPLE for column FOO. Found: long, expected: integer