# LONG as primary key in Hibernate mapping to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to implement persistence of some Java objects via Hibernate mapping to a MySQL table. When I commit I get a message saying 'Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1'.

My hypothesis is that the problem is caused from having a `long`-field in my Java POJO that I want to use as my primary key in the MySQL table. Since I was not able to use datatype LONG as my primary key in MySQL table (ERROR 1170: BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length) I concluded from some googling and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3315941/709438) that BIGINT would be the suitable mapping for `long`. However it is not updating.

My test POJO `Person`is very simple. It has 3 fields: id (long), firstname (String), lastname (String)  with setters and getters, etc.

I do the hibernate mapping in xml (person.hbm.xml) that essentially looks like (minus headings):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="hibernatetest.Person" table="hibernatetest">
   <id name="id" type="long" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="firstname">
   <column name="firstname" />
  </property>
  <property name="lastname">
  <column name="lastname"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My actual java code snippet that is supposed to save or update the record is simple:

```
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();            
Person person = new Person(1,"John","Doe");
session.saveOrUpdate(person);
tr.commit();
```

And here's that thing, this all works just fine if I change the type of `id` to an int (Integer) in the Person object and in the MySQL table. However, I do not have that option for the actual objects that I want to persist so the question is; what am I doing wrong or what should I do to get it to work? Thanks.

ADDING Stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: update hibernatetest set firstname=?, lastname=? where id=?
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3006)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2908)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3237)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1082)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at com.hibernate.test.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:38)
nested transactions not supported
```

UPDATE:
OK, I have finally worked it out. I changed the hibernate generator class from 'native' to 'assigned' and now it works as expected. So now the hibernate mapping looks like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="hibernatetest.Person" table="hibernatetest">
   <id name="id" type="long" column="id" >
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

  <property name="firstname">
   <column name="firstname" />
  </property>
  <property name="lastname">
  <column name="lastname"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Must admit I did not know the meaning of that parameter (copied from somewhere) and had no idea it could cause this much headache. Found this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3315941/709438) which was quite useful.

Apparently I do not have enough credentials to answer my own questions so I guess that it will remain open or if someone provides an empty answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your complete stacktrace, long and BIGINT should work fine, I have used it personally no issues found, please share your stacktrace

Comment: What's your db column type definition? And your id attribute type? Anyway, Bigint for column, and Long for java attribute is allright.

Comment: @mprabhat Done. It has a message saying 'nested transactions not supported' that I did not see before. Don't know what it means though?

Comment: @polypiel Sorry, not sure that I understand the question. The datatype in MySQL is BIGINT(20) and the hibernate config is all that i posted above.

Comment: Realized that the 'nested transactions not supported' is presumably another and separate exception thrown because I am trying to begin a new transaction when the previous transaction had failed. So it is not relevant in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `saveOrUpdate()` method **hibernate fires the insert query if the id of the object is `null` and `update` if it is any other value.** I can see the code,
`Person person = new Person(1,"John","Doe");` setting the `id` to `1` and calling the `saveOrUpdate()` method. I am assuming there are no entries for the id 1 and hence the error is thrown.

To make it work, you need to make the below changes.

1. Change the Type of `id` in person to `Long` from `long`(The wrapper class so that it can support null).
2. Write the constructor `new Person("John","Doe");` and save that object.

It is not a good Idea to keep the `<generator class="assigned"/>` for the transactional data. Instead you should be sticking to the `native` as you were trying first.

I feel this is a cleaner way to solve your initial problem, even though you have found an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct in your assumption that there was no previous record with `id`=1 before `SaveOrUpdate`. I tried to change the class type to `Long` according to your suggestion but it reverts back to the same error if I set the generator to `native`. I didn't understand you second point where you omit `id` from the constructor? The `id` is not an autogenerated id so I need to be able to set it to a specific value.

Comment: I meant that let your DB choose the ID and do not hard code the id to the been while saving. Choose from the options [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) on how can do it.

Comment: OK, got it. In my actual scenario, the `id`'s are provided from an external service and needs to be persisted as such so I cannot let the db decide. If I just change the class type to `Long` and keep a constructor that takes a `Long` I get the original exception. Is that as expected or did I misunderstand something else? You mentioned a risk with generator=`assigned` for transactions. What is the risk?