# pre configured netbeans project with NoSuchMethodError hibernate and spring conflict

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, netbeans, jdbc

so I'm trying to get my Java Application to connect to SQL Server 2012 through the 
[Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774), and everything seems to be going well but hibernate just keeps coming back with `NullExceptions` and won't execute anything within the `try/catch` (hence the `NullException`), I have absolutely no idea why. Here is the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4tVppVj3) from netbeans console (`e.getMessage()`) running hibernate (for the purposes of this question, I am using an example table called `prime_table`).

In the pastebin log, you'll notice ...

> Feb 11, 2013 5:21:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
>   INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null

any ideas on why this is occuring? (I'm not sure, but it may be relevant to the overall stack trace).

**Other logs *(During JSP build)***

- [Netbeans (run)](http://pastebin.com/YZPLtF2h)
- [Apache tomcat](http://pastebin.com/UpPTETXh)
- [Apache tomcat log](http://pastebin.com/HG6CQP18)
- [Sql server ERRORLOG.log](http://pastebin.com/yq6WDUJd)
- **[Hibernate throwable stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/kd7Ssykr) (Update 2/14/2013)**

*All logs will be available up until Mid/Late March 2013*

**Resources, I've been reading**

- [Hibernate Example](https://anshuchoudhury.wordpress.com/category/j2ee/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial-example/)
- [[Help] Null Pointer Exception in session.flush() Hibernate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/559936/ORM/databases/Null-Pointer-Exception-session-flush)
- [hibernate.cfg.xml not found](https://coderanch.com/t/215322/databases/hibernate-cfg-xml)
- [hibernate map java Long to MySQL BIGINT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315941/hibernate-map-java-long-to-mysql-bigint-error)

**Pre Configured Netbeans Project Setup [`commandline: tree /f`](http://iforce.co.nz/i/o5e1aouu.ruz.png)**

[image: netbeans]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/llroxgez.s5s.png))</sub>

**Hibernate.cfg.xml** (Added `"hibernate.cache.provider_class"` as suggested by [Hari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27649/hari))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://Michael-PC:1433;databaseName=PrimeDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">online12</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- Data Mappings -->
    <mapping resource="prime.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Prime**

```
public class Prime {

    private long prime;

    public void setPrime(long nPrime){
        this.prime = nPrime;
    }

    public long getPrime(){
        return this.prime;
    }

}
```

**prime.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="nz.co.xyleap.db.Prime" table="prime_table">
    <id name="prime" type="long" column="prime" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Prime Table**

```
CREATE TABLE prime_table (
    [prime] bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
)
```

**Session function or `FirstExample.java`**

```
public class FirstExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstExample ex = new FirstExample();
        ex.session();
    }

    public void session() {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            // This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for use
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            //Create new instance of Contact and set values in it by reading them from form object
            System.out.println("inserting record 13");
            Prime p = new Prime();
            p.setPrime(13);
            session.save(p);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

As far as I know everything should be correct, and I should be able to insert records from Java Hibernate to my SQL database. But for some reason I can't :-/

UPDATE : Hibernate on its own, runs fine. But in conjunction with Spring, these errors occur. (More information in comments).

Comment: Are you sure that hibernate.cfg.xml is located in the classpath? What is the IDE you are using. Why don't you try giving the absolute path to hibernate.cfg.xml in Configuration constructor.

Comment: Isn't it possible that your code dies here: `SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();` so it doesn't reach giving session a value?

Comment: `Configured SessionFactory: null` is not an error - Hibernate can automatically bind the session factory to JNDI if you specify a `name` attribute to `session-factory` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`. In your case, Hibernate is just logging the session-factory name, which is null.

Comment: Which line of the `session` method is throwing the NullPointerException? The pastebin log Exception is thrown at FirstExample.java line 40, but it's not clear which line of session() that is.

Comment: can you share the error log with stack trace

Comment: @Hari line 40 is `session.flush();`.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary yeah it could be possible that it is dying there, I don't really know on how I could fix it though.

Comment: @shazin I don't really want to give it an absolute path, I prefer relative paths for when it comes to compressing it into a war file.

Comment: Added a `tree /f` of the project setup.

Comment: Do you already have a value for "13" in the prime table?

Comment: @hd1 no the table is completely empty.

Comment: I've been reading topics from google `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)`, could `asm` be causing a conflict?.. because my application is templated from the `New Web Application > Frameworks` (Spring MVC + Hibernate, [jar screendump](http://iforce.co.nz/i/dhly0exp.1p4.png)).

Comment: Hibernate on its own, runs fine. But in conjunction with Spring, these errors occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a library that Hibernate needs at run time. I saw the same behavior as you with your code (MySQL 5, MySQL JDBC driver, Mac OS) until I changed the line:

```
catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

To:

```
catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I then started seeing a whole set of `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundError` messages about libraries that Hibernate was looking for but were not included in my CLASSPATH. I suspect that you're missing a library that Hibernate needs, and because you're catching `Exception` and not `Throwable` - which catches `Error` - you're not seeing the error message. See:

[Why catch Exceptions in Java, when you can catch Throwables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581878/why-catch-exceptions-in-java-when-you-can-catch-throwables)

If you catch the `Throwable` you'll see fairly quickly what libraries and classes you're missing: my guess would be that you're probably missing EHCache (which Hibernate seems to use as a second-level cache by default), CGLIB/ASM, or the Java Transaction API. If you're missing EHCache and you want hibernate to use its own, in-memory Hashtable cache instead of EHCache, add the line below to `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
```

**Update, based on comments to answer:**

I don't use NetBeans and so I haven't run into this problem, but it appears fairly widespread. See:

[Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv)

http://www.hildeberto.com/2008/05/hibernate-and-jersey-conflict-on.html (Reports a similar problem with Hibernate and Jersey in Netbeans)

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2222 (Hibernate bug report mentioning this problem)

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=145589 (Netbeans bug report for bundled Hibernate using older versions of cglib).

The StackOverflow post linked to above has quite a lot of detail. To summarize:

- Hibernate 3.2 uses CGLib 2.1.3 for run-time code generation, to improve performance and to generate proxies for one-to-one and one-to-many mappings.
- CGLib is a higher-level wrapper around ASM, a bytecode manipulation library. CGLib 2.1.3 requires ASM 1.5.3, which is **binary incompatible** with ASM 2.2. ASM 2.2 in turn is a dependency for Spring versions < 2.5.
- To resolve these problems between Hibernate and Spring, Spring 2.5 bundles its own version of asm with a spring package name; later versions of Hibernate use CGLIB 2.2, which also bundles its own version of ASM with a custom package name. The most recent versions of Hibernate do away with CGLIB altogether and use Javassist instead, but NetBeans still bundles Hibernate 3.2.5.

You have a few options, then:

- Update the Hibernate library package in Netbeans with CGLIB 2.2
- Tell Hibernate to use Javassist for runtime code generation. Add this line to hibernate.properties, or specify it as a system property using -D (you can't specify this property in hibernate.cfg.xml, apparently):

  `hibernate.bytecode.provider=javassist`

Good luck, this has been rather an interesting question!

Comment: Thanks ! Hari! :D +1 rep, will mark once I test your solution. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hey Hari, the [Throwable Stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/kd7Ssykr) says something about `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` with occurrences in packages such as `net.sf.cglib.core` (but all these classes exist in the `lib` folder).

Comment: @Killrawr My guess is that the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is coming from mis-matched versions of JARs on your classpath. Make sure you are using compatible versions of all of your third-party libs!

Comment: @JesseWebb Hey the class path for Spring MVC and Hibernate are pre configured from netbeans, `New Project > New Web Application > Frameworks (Select Spring and Hibernate)`, seen [here](http://iforce.co.nz/i/llroxgez.s5s.png).

Comment: @Hari hey hari, just trying your solution now. My project doesn't have a `hibernate.properties` ([hibernate properties](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html)), what should the `.properties` file look like?

Comment: The properties file should look like this:

`hibernate.bytecode.provider=javassist`

Comment: Do I need to include it within the class path?

Comment: If you place hibernate.properties in the "<default package>" section under "Source Packages" in NetBeans, it will get included automatically. If you didn't create hibernate.properties from within NetBeans, just place hibernate.properties in the classpath root (in a NetBeans Web Application projet, in `build/web/WEB-INF/classes`). In that directory, you should have:

`hibernate.cfg.xml
hibernate.properties
prime.hbm.xml
nz/`

Comment: Thanks Hari! it worked :D, just gave you the bounty on the question :)

Answer (score -1):

It is dying at session.flush(); because session is null and something in the try-block is throwing an exception, probably a runtimeexception like nullpointer or something. The fact that the session is null will cause another nullptr and it will hide the original one. So I suggest that you make it

```
if(session!=null)
{
    session.flush();
    session.close();
}
```

and then run it to see what the actual problem is.

I also suggest that you replace the "System.out.println(e.getMessage());" with atleast e.printStackTrace(); or preferably proper logging.

Comment: also the inserts with ? -values are a common syntax for a prepared query with parameters.

Comment: I've already tried this before submitting the question, thanks for the proposed solution though.

Comment: well if you could ofcourse have then posted the resulting exception, since it is bound to be different from the one you posted.

Comment: I don't typically believe your answer, answers the question. Although it may stop the `NullException` from occuring. It does not however address the original problem from which hibernate is attempting to insert data. Regards